# Extracting text from big files in Prolog

Tags: file, prolog

I would like to extract text between a start and end string with SWI-Prolog, e.g., all the titles from Wikipedia dumps. I don't want to use an XML-parser, as I want to deal with different file types in the same way. I got it working for small files, but run into problems for large files.

For big files (e.g., [Romanian Wikipedia](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/rowiki/20170720/rowiki-20170720-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2)) prolog runs out of memory (`prolog -G1G -L1G -T1G -s main.pl -t main`, see content of main.pl below):

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.4.2)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

found: 'Rocarta' 
found: 'Muzică' 
found: 'Iris (formație românească)' 
found: 'Pagina principală'
...[removed hundreds of lines]
found: 'Zadar' 
found: 'Australia' 
found: 'Slovenia' 
found: 'Croația'
ERROR: Out of global stack
   Exception: (5,861) between([60, 116, 105, 116, 108, 101, 62], [60, 47, 116, 105, 116, 108, 101, 62], _264890370, [10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 60, 110, 115|...], []) ?
```

How to accomplish this task with big input files?

**MWE** (`main.pl`):

```
:- use_module(library(pio)).
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
last_call_optimisation(true).

main :- 
    phrase_from_file(between(`<title>`, `</title>`, _), `wiki.xml`).

between(Start, End, Found) --> 
    string(_), string(Start), string(Found), string(End), 
    { format("found: '~s' \n", [Found]) }, 
    between(Start, End, _).
between(_, _, []) --> 
    remainder(_), 
    { format("finished parsing") }.
```

**example input** (`wiki.xml`):

```
<mediawiki>
    >< Don't use an XML parser! ><
    <page><title>Albert Einstein</title></page>
    <page><title>Elvis Presley</title></page>
</mediawiki>
```

**example output** (expected):

```
found: 'Albert Einstein' 
found: 'Elvis Presley' 
finished parsing
```

**Edit**:
If we remove the recursive call from between/3, the output changes, and doesn't correspond to what I expect:

```
 found: 'Albert Einstein' 
 found: 'Albert Einstein</title></page>
     <page><title>Elvis Presley' 
 found: 'Elvis Presley' 
 finished parsing
```

Comment: do you mean moving the second 'between' in front of the first one? Then it doesn't find any titles at all

Comment: if I increase global stack size to 3 gigabyte (-G3G), then the program gets stuck after 52049 titles

Comment: What is the *exact* output you get, please show the entire script including intermediary messages, not just the final error

Comment: I put the entire script as code listening "MWE". I run it with `prolog -G1G -L1G -T1G -s main.pl -t main`. I updated the output

Comment: The size of `Found` can be arbitrarily large. Also this recursive `between//3` is useless.

Comment: @ago: I appreciate any constructive suggestions, how to solve the problem differently. If it helps, we can limit the content of Found to 100 lines. For the recursive call: see edit

Comment: It's not clear from your code, but it sounds like you're reading in the entire file and then parsing? If so, you might want to find a way to do it in pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this construct

```
..., string(_), string(Start),  ...
```

it's *very* inefficient. It turns a linear parse into an exponential one.
But we have a really simple solution, since a string literal performs an exact match in a DCG:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

main(Titles) :-
  %phrase_from_file(between(`<title>`, `</title>`, Titles),`wiki.xml`).
  phrase(between(`<title>`, `</title>`, Titles), `
<mediawiki>
    >< Don't use an XML parser! ><
    <page><title>Albert Einstein</title></page>
    <page><title>Elvis Presley</title></page>
</mediawiki>
  `).


between(_Start, _End, []) --> [].
between(Start, End, [Found|Rest]) -->
    Start, string(String), End,
    { atom_codes(Found, String) },
    !, between(Start, End, Rest).
between(Start, End, List) --> [_], between(Start, End, List).
```

I would simplify the code, though:

```
...
phrase(tag(`title`, Titles), `
...

tag(_Tag, []) --> [].
tag(Tag, [Found|Rest]) -->
    "<", Tag, ">", string(String), "</", Tag, ">",
    { atom_codes(Found, String) },
    !, tag(Tag, Rest).
tag(Tag, List) --> [_], tag(Tag, List).
```

My bet is that on large files this is slightly more efficient.
It's also easy to generalize:

...
  phrase(tags([`title`, `footnote`], Contents), `
  ...

```
tags(_Tags, []) --> [].
tags(Tags, [Key-Found|Rest]) -->
    "<", {member(Tag, Tags)}, Tag, ">", string(String), "</", Tag, ">",
    { maplist(atom_codes, [Found,Key], [String,Tag]) },
    !, tags(Tags, Rest).
tags(Tags, List) --> [_], tags(Tags, List).
```

but not very efficient. Better (but should profile to prove it)

```
...
"<", string(Tag), ">", {memberchk(Tag, Tags)}, string(String), "</", Tag, ">",
...
```

**Edit**: at least on a small set of Tags, `"<", {member(Tag, Tags)}, Tag, ">"` seems to require a lot less inferences than `"<", string(Tag), ">", {memberchk(Tag, Tags)},`.